# Сделать запрос, чтобы были показаны несколько конкретных полей mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Я впервые на mongodb, и у меня нет идей ка к реализовать выгрузку нескольких полей и показать в определённом формате.
У меня есть такие данные

```
{
  country: 'country1',
  city: 'North' 
  location: { ll: [ 106.796, -131.666 ] }
},

{
  country: 'country1',
  city: 'New' 
  location: { ll: [ -113.975, 110.905 ] }
},

{
  country: 'country2',
  city: 'South'
  location: { ll: [ 67.998, 70.345 ] }
},

{
  country: 'country2',
  city: 'West'
  location: { ll: [ -36.067, 65.817 ] }
}
```

И надо чтобы оно после запроса выглядело так:

```
{
country: 'country1', long: [106.796, -113.975], lat: [-131.666, 110.905]
}
```

Использую нативную JS  и  mongod (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb).

Спасибо.